# libsybdb.a(dblib.o)' does not contain bitcode

Tags: swift

When I try to run my project on my phone in xcode 11.2 beta 2, I get the following error:

```
"ld: '/.../Pods/SQLClient/SQLClient/SQLClient/SQLClient/libsybdb.a(dblib.o)' does not contain bitcode. rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target.
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) "
```

How can I fix this is causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable bitcode.
Go to your Pod SQLClient Target and disable in the Build Settings Bitcode or disable bitcode in main project target.